# How to replace a VERY specific color (HEX code) for another one in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, palette, color-match

I'm working in doing a map for a 2D game. The image is saved to PNG and loaded by the game. However, the game detects true black (HEX #000000) as background, and makes it transparent in-game. Since I'm adding custom pictures to the map, some of them have this black color, which I would like to replace those pixels with anything *just above* true black, like HEX #000001.

If this modification is possible to do with a certain image or selection, instead of at the end when saving the whole file, that would be appreciated.

File will be saved as RGB, PNG-8

Comment: Magic wand global and no tolerance

Comment: @joojaa by global you mean that you can use the magic wand to select all the pixels that matches the color, even if they aren't contiguos / in a certain area?

Comment: Yes, the options name is continuous if you want them to only select local, if you uncheck that it samples all pixels globaly. Make sure that you ave the options panel enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this can be done in numerous ways, since it's a black color things are even easier. Here are two ideas.

- Destructive:

Use `Replace Color` on blacks of your layers and add +1 lightness

[image]

[image]

- Non-destructive with Blending Options:

Place a color layer or adjustment layer that adds to brightness on to of your layers, add to brightness and set `Blend If` property to be 0..1: this will blend that layer only if layers below contain black color. In this example I've put a color layer that's filled with 1% bright grey:

[image]